# SQL - I want a function or a trigger that would join tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, database-design, view

First off I'm a newbie on SQL before anything else...
I'm making a small database for the purpose of learning the language. My problem lies on the searches that I want to make possible.

To further explain, I made a database on games and consoles, something like this:

Table game:

```
- id (pkey)
- genre
- id_platform (foreign key)
- id_platform2 (foreign key)
- game_name
```

a second table platform:

```
- id_platform (pkey)
- console_name
```

Basically what I wanted to do is if a person does a search on, say, PC games, they will get the name, genre, id_platform number with what I have but I wanted this search to yeild the platform name too automatically when said search would be done.

I have tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    game
    INNER JOIN
    plataform ON game.id_plataform = plataform.id_plataform
    INNER JOIN 
    plataform2 ON game.id_plataforma = plataforma.id_plataforma;
```

but this just does a search, is there any way to make this automatic?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what you mean when you say automatic? You will still have to run a query to get any kind of result set. To have a table that is ready to be queried on demand with the data already in the shape you want, create a view.  http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-views-sql-tutorial/ or http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-materialized-views/

Comment: If a game can be in more than one platform then you need a third table linking the game table to the platform table.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is:

```
SELECT g.id, g.genre, g.game_name, p1.console_name as p1_name, p2.console_name as p2_name
FROM game g 
LEFT JOIN platform p1 ON g.id_platform = p1.id_platform
LEFT JOIN platform p2 ON g.id_platform2 = p2.id_platform
WHERE g.game_name LIKE 'your_search';
```

*** edit ***  Above code does not cover the following advices to normalization and should work on the data structure as given in the question!  *** end edit ***

But you really should read about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) before starting to extend your database.

What you in this example need are three tables:

1. Game: id, genre, game_name
2. Platform: id, console_name
3. Game2Platform: game_id, platform_id

Then you can search for a game like this (consider you will get one result entry per platform the game supports):

```
SELECT g.id as game_id, g.genre, g.game_name, p.id as platform_id, p.console_name
FROM game g 
LEFT JOIN game2platform g2p ON g.id = g2p.game_id
LEFT JOIN platform p ON g2p.platform_id = p.id
WHERE g.game_name LIKE 'your_search';
```

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto: I edited the answer to stress the difference between my answer to the original question and the advice to optimize the data structure which is adviced in your answer as well.

Comment: My tables are actually set up like that, I have 1 main game table and 2 platform ones. A problem that also keeps showing is that whenever I try to create a view... and I can't really explain this better... the data gets all jumbled up. Games I have with no platform2 get a platform that should be on the following game... I'm gonna try to get a picture and edit this post with it.

Comment: @Xiriko: You are having 2 platform tables? Ok, that's really weird. Please try to switch your database structure as mentioned in my answer (or in Clodoaldo Netos answer), then use the select query I've just added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a third table linking games to platforms:

```
create table game (
    game_id integer primary key,
    genre text,
    game_name text
);

create table platform (
    platform_id integer primary key,
    console_name text
);

create table game_platform (
    game_id integer references game (game_id),
    platform_id integer references platform (platform_id),
    primary key (game_id, platform_id)
);
```

Create a view to make it easier to query:

```
create view game_view as
select *
from
    game g
    inner join
    game_platform gp using (game_id)
    inner join
    platform p using (platform_id)
;
```

Now the query is just:

```
select *
from game_view;
```